# Getting the data from the referenced object in Moongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

i have created two models i.e., User and todos. In todos schema i am referencing to user through

```
user: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
```

Now in the database, the object is created in the todo as user > id,I can display the id in ejs using details.user.id but i want to access the other properties of this user, like his name and email. Please help me

user schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  admin: Boolean,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

todo schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const todoTaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  user: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    user: String,
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("TodoTask", todoTaskSchema);
```

[Document in Mongoose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGnNV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `populate` the `user` reference:

```
const task = await TodoTask.find({}).populate('user').exec()
```

Also, try to change your `TodoTask` schema declaration:

```
const todoTaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
});
```

You should then be able to access user property with `task.user.<user-property>`.

Finally, you should modify your view to display the `name` property from `details.user` directly:

```
<ul class="todo-list">
  <% todoTasks.forEach(details => { %>
  <li class="todo-list-item">
    <div class="todo-list-item-name"><%= details.content %></div>
    <a href="/edit/<%= details._id %>" class="edit">
      <span class="fas fa-edit"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="/remove/<%= details._id %>" class="remove">
      <span class="fas fa-times"></span> </a
    >by &nbsp;<%=details.user.name %>
  </li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi @lpizzinidev thanks for your reply, i used your code and when i am using task.user.name, it is not displaying anything. However, if i use task.user.id, it is displaying the id.

Comment: @SyedShujaShah Try to change `user` schema declaration in `todoTaskSchema` (see edited answer)

Comment: here is what i am trying to do in getAllTodos 
`const getAllTodos = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.user.admin === true) {
    const task = await TodoTask.find({})
      .populate("user")
      .exec((err, tasks) => {
        return res.render("admin-dashboard.ejs", {
          todoTasks: tasks,
          displayName: req.user.name,
        });
      });`
what should i do to fetch the name of the user?

Comment: It depends on how you want to display it on `admin-dashboard`. Can you post the content of that file?

Comment: In admin dashboard file, i want to show the name of the user along with the todo
`<ul class="todo-list">
        <% todoTasks.forEach(details => { %>
        <li class="todo-list-item">
          <div class="todo-list-item-name"><%= details.content %></div>
          <a href="/edit/<%= details._id %>" class="edit">
            <span class="fas fa-edit"></span>
          </a>
          <a href="/remove/<%= details._id %>" class="remove">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span> </a
          >by &nbsp;<%=details.task.user.name %>
        </li>
        <% }) %>
      </ul>
`

Comment: You should be able to access user properties directly from `details.user` (see edited answer)

Comment: one more thing, when i used the TodoTask Schema declaration that you shared, i am not able to post the todo, i am getting the error " user: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value"

Comment: You are probably trying to add the whole `User` object to the schema. You will just need to add the `ObjectId` of the `User` and then populate it when querying.